# Is it ok to use the phrase "has fallen a due" rather than just "has fallen due"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns

I'm not after a change in meaning (the meaning being; the time to pay an incurred debt has arrived. *could be better phrased I bet*) yet it just seems to sound better to say has fallen a due rather than fallen due. I guess the question becomes can I use "a due" as noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. "Due" is used here as an adjective, so you wouldn't say "The debt has fallen a due" any more than you would say "The apple is a red.", for example.

"Due" is sometimes used as a noun ("I gave him his due." or "I paid my dues."), but not here; the appropriate wording is "The debt has fallen due." or "The debt is due."

Comment: what about "the debt has a fallen due"? Or anything that is owed for that matter.

Comment: +1  Also, we should note that *fall* is not a transitive verb, so something can't "fall (a noun)" even if *a due* were a correct noun.

Comment: @sle7en - No, "the debt has a fallen due" is not correct either, for the same reason: *due* is not a noun, so you can't say "a due".